# No find member in std::vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Is there any particular reason why `std::vector` does not have a member function `find`? Instead you have to call `std::find` (and `#include <algorithm>`).

The reason why I ask is that I think it would be a good thing to be able to change container class in some piece of implementation without having to change the code wherever the container is accessed. Say I replace an `std::vector` where the implementation uses `std::find` with an `std::map`. Then I also have to replace the call of `std::find` with a call to the member `find`, unless I want to keep the linear complexity of `std::find`. Why not just have a member `find` for all container classes, which finds an element with whatever algorithm is best suited for each container?

Comment: I don't see the problem. `std::find` is generic and works for all objects/constructs which provide an iterator adhering to the `InputIterator` concept.

Comment: Because `std::map::find` looks for a key while `std::find` looks for a pair `key, value`, so these are two different algorithms.

Comment: The question is not why there is an `std::find`. It's why there is NOT a member function `find`. Obviously `std::find` should not be removed...

Comment: Interesting reading: [how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

Comment: Note that the future ranged-based standard library and a complete uniform call syntax (and possibly with the help of Concepts) would allow `std::vector{ 2, 3, 4 }.find( 2 )` without modifying `std::vector`, without ruining its encapsulation. But there's still a lot of work left for it to be accepted in future standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) only requires two `InputIterator`s to work and not an `std::vector`. As such, one implementation works for all containers including STL containers, *and standard arrays*, and anything that can supply an `InputIterator`, including for example an [`istream_iterator()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/) - nice!

So, instead of providing one `find()` method for every container (and take into account that for some it might not possible, like standard arrays), one single, generic `find()` function is provided for all. This likely makes your code more resilient to change than adding a `find()` method for each container since it provides a consistent interface to search in any collection: an input stream from console, network etc., or just a basic array. This is an important aspect of the STL *generic design* philosophy: you can search for elements in any *collection/range* defined by two `InputIterator`s.

The downside, as you note, is that in some cases, better performance may be achieved using the container's own method, which can make special assumptions to improve performance (similarly for `list::remove`, `unorderd_map::remove/find()` etc.). For this reason, containers can provide (and this is a well known design feature of STL) a  method *specifically for performance reasons*: for example a `std::unordered_map` does not require one to iterate through the entire map to find an element.

In summary, since the generic `std::find` works efficiently for a vector, there is no need to provide  a member function, since it might enforce even less portable design.

For all things STL related see [The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition](http://www.cppstdlib.com/)

Answer (score 0):

std::find is a common solution. some classes need some kind of specialization of this function so that's why they have them locally (as i remember Meyers said that if a class has its own function-member then you should use it instead of globally defined)